# How to apply "mutate" to each element of the column when elements differ from each other?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have parsed a corpus and I now have something like this, from *text1*:

```
  doc_id sentence_id token_id        token        lemma   pos   entity
1  text1           1        1 Introductory introductory   ADJ         
2  text1           1        2    statement    statement  NOUN         
3  text1           1        3         with         with   ADP         
4  text1           1        4          Q&A          Q&A PROPN    ORG_B
5  text1           1        5         \n           \n   SPACE         
6  text1           1        6         Jean         Jean PROPN PERSON_B
```

to *text100*

```
doc_id sentence_id token_id token  lemma   pos entity
758712 text100         273       32  task   task  NOUN       
758713 text100         273       33     .      . PUNCT       
758714 text100         273       34              SPACE       
758715 text100         274        1 Thank  thank  VERB       
758716 text100         274        2   you -PRON-  PRON       
758717 text100         274        3     .      . PUNCT
```

Now, I am trying to change each element of the column **doc_id** so that whenever there is *text1* it will appear *text134*, whenever there is *text2* it will appear *text135* and so on (basically from 1-100 to 134-233).

I just did it for *text1* using the following code:

```
parse2 %>% mutate(doc_id = recode(doc_id, text1 = "text134"))
```

How can I apply the same logic to each text from 1 to 100? Trying to create some loop but I quite new to R and I am just stuck with it.

Can you help me out?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the text from `doc_id` so that you only have numbers left and add 133 to it to get `new_id`.

```
transform(df, new_id = paste0("text", as.integer(sub("\\D+", "", doc_id)) + 133))
#Or if it is always "text" in doc_id remove that directly
#transform(df, new_id = paste0("text", as.integer(sub("text", "", doc_id)) + 133))

#  id doc_id  new_id
#1  1  text1 text134
#2  2  text1 text134
#3  3  text1 text134
#4  4  text2 text135
#5  5  text2 text135
#6  6  text2 text135
#7  7  text3 text136
#8  8  text3 text136
#9  9  text3 text136
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:9, doc_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("text1", "text2", "text3"), 
class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

With Ronak's Data

```
df %>%
    mutate(doc_id = paste0("text", 133 + as.integer(gsub("text(\\d+)", "\\1", doc_id))))
#  id  doc_id
#1  1 text134
#2  2 text134
#3  3 text134
#4  4 text135
#5  5 text135
#6  6 text135
#7  7 text136
#8  8 text136
#9  9 text136
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_c` from `stringr` along with `parse_number` from `readr`

```
library(stringr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(new_id = str_c("text", parse_number(doc_id) + 133))
#  id doc_id  new_id
#1  1  text1 text134
#2  2  text1 text134
#3  3  text1 text134
#4  4  text2 text135
#5  5  text2 text135
#6  6  text2 text135
#7  7  text3 text136
#8  8  text3 text136
#9  9  text3 text136
```

---

Or another option is to convert the 'doc_id' to index by `match`ing with the `unique` elements, add 133 and `paste` with 'text'

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(doc_id = str_c('text', 133 + match(doc_id, unique(doc_id))))
```

It can also be used with `base R`

```
df1$doc_id <- with(df1, paste0('text', 133 + match(doc_id, unique(doc_id))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:9, doc_id = c("text1", "text1", "text1", 
"text2", "text2", "text2", "text3", "text3", "text3")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```